# I have problems to embed youtube Videos in my nextjs app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, flash, youtube, vercel

I get this messages in my console:

1. This type serveral for all attributs of the player: Feature Policy:

Unbekannte Funktionalität (Feature) "picture-in-picture" wird ignoriert.

2. if I press the play button: Quellübergreifende (Cross-Origin) Anfrage blockiert:

Die Gleiche-Quelle-Regel verbietet das Lesen der externen Ressource auf https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/962985656/?backend=innertube&cname=56&cver=20231205&foc_id=pOiY428vg-97Shtu4eXuwg&label=followon_view&ptype=no_rmkt&random=164395811&cv_attributed=0. (Grund: CORS-Kopfzeile 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' fehlt). Statuscode: 302.

3. MouseEvent.mozPressure sollte nicht mehr verwendet werden. Verwenden Sie PointerEvent.pressure stattdessen.
4. Anfrage für Zugriff auf Cookies oder Speicher für "https:...
5. WEBGL_debug_renderer_info is deprecated in Firefox and will be removed. Please use RENDERER.

Hier ist mein Code:

[Git Hub repositorys](https://github.com/mumbablooz/tarifvertrag)

I tryed to impimentate react-youtube

I tryed to deploy the app at vercel. it dont works.
at dev mode I can play videos but i have the messages in the console.

What can I do?
Please help me!